# How to improve the result of pytesseract?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am applying **pytesseract** to my project and I did not get the desired results, so I started to optimize a bit ...

- I trained the font from the website
- I made the image binary (Black and white)
- I put only the characters that will have the images (A to Z in
  uppercase)
- Since they are single character, I put in config *"--psm 10"*
- In a desperate measure, **with Photoshop I raised the DPI from 72 to 600**

But even with all this and having a clear isolated and visible letter, **instead of the "A" I get a "T"** ... Is there something where I am failing? I would really appreciate your help :)

```
import pytesseract
import pyautogui
import cv2
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'



celda1 = cv2.imread('imagen.jpg')



sret=pytesseract.image_to_string(celda1, config="-c tessedit"
                                         "_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
                                         " --psm 10"
                                         " -l osd"
                                         " ")



print(sret)
```

[image]

Comment: as I know if text is too small then it may have problem, but if text is too big then it may have problem too. Tesseract documentation: [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality)

Comment: for this single image I get `"A"` when I remove `" -l osd"`

Comment: right friend, it was that, it works perfect, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Another way is to train ``tesseract`` .:)